# Spring boot- keycloak hardcoded roles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, roles

Is it possible to implement "hasAnyRole" dynamically instead of hardcoding it inside service, so that the user can change it whenever he wants?
I know there is a way to do something similar with scopes but it doesnt fit into requirements needed.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/test/roles").hasAnyRole("BYREAD", "BYEDIT")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you expect your user to update the roles, you may be able to accomplish it using a web security expressions that refers to a `Bean`.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test/roles").access("@permission.check(authentication)")
            // ...
}

@Bean
public PermissionChecker permission() {
    // ...
}

static class PermissionChecker {

    public boolean check(Authentication authentication) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

In the example above `@permission` refers to the `Bean` called `permission`.
You could add any logic you need to the `check` method.

For more details see [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-access-web-beans) in the Spring Security reference documentation.